# Substring method throwing a ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, substring

Using the .Substring method, I'm getting some weird behavior. For example, when I express the value:

```
    "(8) + (2)".Substring(3,6);
```

I get the result of: " + (2)"

However, when I increment the lower index simply by one, like this:

```
    "(8) + (2)".Substring(4,6);
```

I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException thrown.

Also, it seems like it's not grabbing the correct part of the substring, since the result of " + (2)" would instead have been from calling:

```
    "(8) + (2)".Substring(3,8);
```

because of the spaces, where:

```
    "(8) + (2)".Substring(3,6);
```

would instead result in: " + (".

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well your string is 9 characters.  4+6 is 10.  That's past the length of the string.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who answered. I'm confused on why I get so many down-votes for a genuine question -- isn't this supposed to be a knowledge-sharing website for people trying to learn?

Comment: Also, I'm sure I'm not the first student to have run into this problem in transitioning from Java to C#, and I'm sure this post could help people in the future. Yet it's still down-voted so heavily.

Comment: Checking the documentation for `String.SubString` would have been helpful, too.  You might even have noticed that it is behaving exactly as described in the documentation.  Weird behavior, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason why you are getting an ArgumentOutOfRangeException is that you are incorrectly using the SubString method. In .Net, The signature for the SubString method is `SubString(int index, int length)`. That means that when you perform

```
"(8) + (2)".Substring(3,6);
```

You are asking for a SubString starting at index 3, the space before the + symbol, that is 6 characters long. So you will get the SubString “ + (2)”. If you were to say SubString(2, 3) you would get the SubString “) +”.

Now the reason why you get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException is just like what Amy said

> 4+6=10

You string is only 9 characters long. If you were to ask for a string starting at index 4 that is 5 characters long you’d get “+ (2)”.

If you need more information review the docs from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Gregory! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You've mistaken the second argument of `String.Substring(int, int)` to be end index, while it is in fact the number of characters to take starting from start index (the first argument). See [String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jakub. I appreciate it greatly.